# The Metapost path fullcircle

Tags: metapost

Is the MetaPost path fullcircle cyclic?

I attempted to find the answer in "METAPOST - A User's Manual" but had no luck.

UPDATE:

show cycle fullcircle;

will print the answer `true`.

Comment: How do you mean? Have you tried. Afair a closed curve in mp is cyclic as in you can go around as many times you want. (though I don't use metapost that much any more)

Comment: I know that there is an operator `cycle`, but I don't know how to print the result of `cycle fullcircle`.

Comment: Draw a point at certain times on the curve. Afair  fullcircle goes 0 1 2 3 4 0, as in (assuming complex plane), 1, I, -1, -i, 1. So at time 2 it is at (-1,0).

Comment: As far as I understand a path like `(0,0) .. (1,1) ..(0,0)` is open (?) and `(0,0) .. (1,1) .. cycle` is closed? So to test whether a path is cyclic, I need to use the `cycle` operator.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you need to know if a given path is closed? What do you need this information for?

Comment: I am implementing a Metapost inspired library in Racket called MetaPict. I have defined a curve `fullcircle` as in Metapost. Internally curves are represented as lists of Bezier curves and a flag `cyclic?`.  In order for Metapost users to get the least amount of surprises I am trying to follow the lead of Metapost. 

I think I have it: print is called `show`, so `show cycle fullcircle` prints `true`.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at plain.mp and not just the manual.

Comment: Tak for tippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A path such as

```
(0,0)..(1,0)..(1,1)..(0,1)..(0,0)
```

is open. You can check this by doing

```
*path p;

*p:=(0,0)..(1,0)..(1,1)..(0,1)..(0,0);

*show point 3 of p;
>> (0,1)
*show point 3.5 of p;
>> (-0.20709,0.49998)
*show point 4 of p;
>> (0,0)
*show point 4.1 of p;
>> (0,0)
*show point 10 of p;
>> (0,0)
*show point 12 of p;
>> (0,0)
```

On the other hand, we can see

```
*p:=(0,0)..(1,0)..(1,1)..(0,1)..cycle;

*show point 3 of p;
>> (0,1)
*show point 3.5 of p;
>> (-0.20709,0.49998)
*show point 4 of p;
>> (0,0)
*show point 4.1 of p;
>> (0.08765,-0.07457)
*show point 10 of p;
>> (1,1)
*show point 12 of p;
>> (0,0)
```

Going on:

```
*p:=(0,0)..(1,0)..(1,1)..(0,1)..(0,0);

*show cycle p;
>> false
*p:=(0,0)..(1,0)..(1,1)..(0,1)..cycle;

*show cycle p;
>> true
```

You can get the definition of `fullcircle`:

```
*show fullcircle;
>> Path at line 0:
(0.5,0)..controls (0.5,0.13261) and (0.44731,0.25978)
 ..(0.35355,0.35355)..controls (0.25978,0.44731) and (0.13261,0.5)
 ..(0,0.5)..controls (-0.13261,0.5) and (-0.25978,0.44731)
 ..(-0.35355,0.35355)..controls (-0.44731,0.25978) and (-0.5,0.13261)
 ..(-0.5,0)..controls (-0.5,-0.13261) and (-0.44731,-0.25978)
 ..(-0.35355,-0.35355)..controls (-0.25978,-0.44731) and (-0.13261,-0.5)
 ..(0,-0.5)..controls (0.13261,-0.5) and (0.25978,-0.44731)
 ..(0.35355,-0.35355)..controls (0.44731,-0.25978) and (0.5,-0.13261)
 ..cycle
```

and this is cyclic.

Actually you don't find the definition in `plain.mp`, because `fullcircle` is defined by `fullcircle = makepath pencircle;`, but when the path has been built it can be shown.